# Are reference requests okay?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question in Cross Validated about book recommendations--specifically for statistics books for the mathematically literate (as opposed to many books that are aimed at the math-phobic).

Is this an appropriate question to ask?

Comment: That question has been asked at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-book-would-you-recommend-for-non-statistician-scientists .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are OK. Tag it with [books](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books).

Comment: Cool, thanks! :)

Comment: I would not say they are "OK", but "can be tolerated as community wiki.." otherwise you get the "infinite list of X" question with everyone posting their favorite flavor of ice cream..

Comment: @Jeff We accept them because they proved to behave well on this site.

Comment: still, I would *seriously* hesitate to give this question a blanket no-strings-attached "they are OK". Better to say "OK under certain conditions, but be careful."